# Intellj : how to get svn url of a file

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

I am using jetbrains Intellj and PyCharm : I cannot see any way to get the svn url of a file.
On eclipse this was easy : right click on the file and "properties"

But how to do that with Intellj or PyCharm ?

Comment: You might need to configure the SVN Repository window : 
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.3/configuring-subversion-repository-location.html

Answer (score 4):

I found a way :

I the settings I declared an "external tool" configured like this :

```
Name: svn info
Program: /usr/bin/svn
Parameters: info $FilePath$
Working directory: $FileDir$
```

Now I can right click a file -> external tools -> "svn info"

et voilà !